# Adjusting small multiples sparklines

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I have an heatmap that show some data and a sparkline for each line of the heatmap.
If the user click on a row label, then the data are ordered in decreasing order, so each rect is placed in the right position.
Viceversa, if the user click on a column label.

Each react is placed in the right way but I'm not able to place the sparkline.

[**Here the code**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jJSFIXX8WqXZV3CXvY8T).

When the user click on a row label, also the path inside the svg containing the sparkline should be updated.
And then, when the user click on a column label, the `svg` containing the sparkline should be placed in the correct line.

To place the svg in the right place, I try to use the `x` and `y` attributes of `svg`. They are updated but the svg doesn't change its position. Why?
Here is a piece of code related to that:

```
var t = svg.transition().duration(1000);
var values = []; 
var sorted;
sorted = d3.range(numRegions).sort(function(a, b) {
    if(sortOrder) {
        return values[b] - values[a];
    } 
    else {
        return values[a] - values[b];
    }
});

t.selectAll('.rowLabel')
    .attr('y', function(d, k) {
        return sorted.indexOf(k) * cellSize;
    });
```

Also, I don't know how to change the path of every sparkline `svg`. I could take the data and order them manually, but this is only good for the row on which the user has clicked and not for all the others.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical and horizontal re-positioning/redrawing of those sparklines require different approaches:

#### Vertical adjustment

For this solution I'm using `selection.sort`, which:

> Returns a new selection that contains a copy of each group in this selection sorted according to the compare function. After sorting, re-inserts elements to match the resulting order.

So, first, we set our selection:

```
var sortedSVG = d3.selectAll(".data-svg")
```

Then, since `selection.sort` deals with data, we bind the datum, which is the index of the SVG regarding your `sorted` array:

```
.datum(function(d){
    return sorted.indexOf(+this.dataset.r)
})
```

Finally, we compare them in ascending order:

```
.sort(function(a,b){
    return d3.ascending(a,b)
});
```

Have in mind that the change is immediate, not a slow and nice transition. This is because the elements are re-positioned in the DOM, and the new structure is painted immediately. For having a slow transition, you'll have to deal with HTML and CSS inside the container div (which may be worth a new specific question).

#### Horizontal adjustment

The issue here is getting all the relevant data from the selection:

```
var sel = d3.selectAll('rect[data-r=\'' + k + '\']')
    .each(function() {
        arr.push({value:+d3.select(this).attr('data-value'),
            pos: +d3.select(this).attr('data-c')});
    });
```

And sorting it according to `data-c`. After that, we map the result to a simple array:

```
var result = arr.sort(function(a,b){
        return sorted.indexOf(a.pos) - sorted.indexOf(b.pos)
    }).map(function(d){
        return d.value
    });
```

#### Conclusion

Here is the updated Plunker: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/85fIXWxmX0l42cHx or http://plnkr.co/edit/85fIXWxmX0l42cHx

PS: You'll need to re-position the circles as well.