# Update the heatmap based on the selected data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap

I created an heatmap and some sparklines following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982686/placing-a-circle-over-a-sparkline-when-the-user-changes-the-ordering-of-the-data).
In the example the user could click on the labels of the rows and those of the columns, in my case I kept only the possibility to click on the columns labels.

That example was perfect for my data, only I need to update the heatmap based on the radio buttons selection.

The first radio buttons allow you to choose the type of area (A or B).
The second group of radio buttons allow you to choose the daily data to be displayed.
However, the data are "incomplete": not all the months have daily data but only April and December.
So if you select the April or December radio button, the daily data on the heatmap are shown, otherwise the monthly ones are shown.

The example works but it is very primitive because the heatmap is deleted and recreated every time.

```
// Return to the initial order when the user clicks on the button
d3.select('#initialOrder').on('click', function() {
    var trans = heat.transition().duration(1000);
    var sortedYear = Array.from(Array(numYLabels).keys());
    trans.selectAll('.cell')
        .attr('y', function(d) { 
            var row = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr('data-r'));
            return sortedYear.indexOf(row)*cellSize;
        });
    trans.selectAll('.rowLabel')
        .attr('y', function(d, k) {
            return sortedYear.indexOf(k) * cellSize;
        });
    sortedYear.forEach(function(d) {
        d3.select('#data-svg-' + d).raise();
    });
});

// Area radio button change selection
d3.selectAll('input[name=area-rb]').on('change', function() {
    areaSelected = d3.select('input[name="area-rb"]:checked').property("value");
    console.log('areaSelected:', areaSelected);
    d3.select('#heatmapSvg').remove();
    d3.selectAll('.data-svg').remove();
    createHeatmap();
});

// Month radio button change selection
d3.selectAll('input[name=month-rb]').on('change', function() {
    monthSelected = d3.select('input[name="month-rb"]:checked').property("value");
    console.log('monthSelected:', monthSelected);
    if(avaibleDayData.includes(monthSelected)) {
        d3.select('#heatmapSvg').remove();
        d3.selectAll('.data-svg').remove();
        createHeatmap();
    }
    else {
        monthSelected = 'nothing';
        d3.select('#heatmapSvg').remove();
        d3.selectAll('.data-svg').remove();
        createHeatmap();
    }   
});
```

I found [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/iblind/b394c943fef0aedc569d) that allow to update the heatmap but I can't able to adapt the code.
In the example, data changes only value and not "shape". That is, the number of labels remains the same. In my case, the situation is a bit more complicated.

I create a [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/i4RPkRSEzinPrVozqoQe) with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example where a LOT of d3's enter/update/exit selection can be implemented.

Yeah, I agree: recreating a chart on every change isn't a good solution.

Okay, so here's a fork of your Plunkr using **enter/update/merge/exit** methods.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2v8YQoZSClhKpW2U1pwi?p=preview

A preview of how I got the *merge* selection done: Let's take `rowLabels` for example:

```
// make region labels
var rowLabels = rowLabelGroup
    .selectAll('text.rowLabel')
    .data(yLabelsNames);

// ENTER SELECTION FOR COL LABELS
// ENTER + UPDATE
// After merging the entered elements with the update selection,
// apply operations to both.

rowLabels
    .enter().append('text').attr('class', 'rowLabel mono')
    .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
    .style('text-anchor', 'end')
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('font-weight', 'bold').style('fill', 'red');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('font-weight', 'normal').style('fill', 'black');
    })
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * cellSize;
    })
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        return 'translate(-3, 11)';
    })
    .merge(rowLabels)
    .attr('name', function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .attr('id', function(d) {
        return 'rowLabel_' + yLabelsNames.indexOf(d);           
    })
    .attr('label-r', function(d) {
        return yLabelsNames.indexOf(d);
    });


// exit/remove elements which are no longer in use
rowLabels.exit().remove();
```

Similarly, these methods have been applied to `colLabels`, `cells` and `sparkLineSvgs` as you can notice in the code.

And regarding appending of the SVGs, I've moved that code to **outside** the `updateHeatmap` function. And yes, btw, I've changed the name of the function from `createHeatmap` to `updateHeatmap`.

And I did encounter an issue while hovering over for the tooltip i.e. the tooltip flickered a lot. To counter that, I've added `pointer-events:none` to `.d3-tip` tooltip.

Go through the code and let me know if I've missed on anything or if you face issue understanding any part.

Hope it helps.